# Explicit var type in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

If I have a type t

`type t = C of string;;`

And want to explicitly define a type of the variable to be type t:

`let b : t = C 'MyString';;`

Can I do it in OCaml?

Comment: Actually, `let b : t = Var 'MyString';;` would compile if you made the effort of fixing the problems that you should have fixed when redacting your question. Strings are enclosed in `"` and your constructor is named `C`, not `Var`.

Answer (score 11):

You don't *need* to be explicit

```
let b = C mystring
let b = C "a string litteral"
```

You *can* be explicit, but it dy oesn't add anything

```
let b : t = C foo
```

The preferred way in general is to use type inference without annotating types, and only be explicit about the type of the identifiers exported to other modules, through the associated `.mli` interface file.

In this case, a type annotation doesn't add anything as the `C` constructor already is a kind of tag/annotation : `C something` is necessarily of type `t`, there is no possible confusion.

Answer (score 5):

You can, using either that syntax, or the alternate one:

```
let b = (C foo : t)
```

Adding type constraints in this fashion does not usually serve any purpose in a well-formed program, because the type inference algorithm can handle all of it correctly on its own. There are a few exceptions (mostly involving the object-oriented side), but they're quite rare.

Such annotations are mostly useful when a type error happens and you need to understand why a certain expression has a certain type when you expected it to have another, because you can type-annotate intermediate values to have the type error move up through your source code.

Note that there's another way of annotating types, which is to define a signature for your modules. In your example above, your module body would contain:

```
let b = C foo
```

And your module signature would contain :

```
val b : t
```

This is especially useful when you need assumptions inside the module to be invisible to other modules. For instance, when using polymorphic variants:

```
let user_type = `Admin
```

Here, you only want to handle the administrator account, but you need the rest of your code to be aware that other account types exist, so you would write in the signature that:

```
val user_type : [`Admin|`Member|`Guest]
```

This type is technically correct, but could not have been guessed by the type inference algorithm.